# Linux Fedora 22 dnf ImportError?

Tags: linux, fedora, dnf

I'm a Linux newbie. Still figuring out sysadmin/installation procedures. Recently after a software installation, the following error has been showing up. All dnf functions are not working.

Even Fedora update as root user:

```
dnf update
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/bin/dnf", line 57, in 
>       from dnf.cli import main
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/**init**.py", line 31, in 
>       import dnf.base
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 26, in 
>       from dnf.comps import CompsQuery
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/comps.py", line 29, in 
>       import dnf.util
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnf/util.py", line 31, in 
>       import librepo
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/librepo/**init**.py", line 1001, in 
>       import librepo._librepo
>
> ImportError: /lib64/libssh2.so.1: symbol EVP_rc4, version libcrypto.so.10 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference

Comment: [Fedora 22 is EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life). Update to some supported version to get some relevant answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Although updating to a newer version via dnf doesn't work as well. Any suggestion would be  appreciated. Thanks.